# RMySQL package not available for R 3.1.0. What else can be used?

Tags: r, installation, package, rmysql

I was trying to use a package to connect R and MySQL to run stats on a database in a local environment. It seems like the package "RMySQL" is not available for the current version of R.

### Following is what R spit out:

> install.packages("RMySQL")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

package ‘RMySQL’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :

### package ‘RMySQL’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)

Two quick questions:

1. What is the difference between source package and binary?
2. Is there another package available that does the same job and is compatible with R 3.1.0?

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Note that "is not available (for R version 3.1.0)" isn't meant to imply that the package is *known* to be available for other versions.

Comment: Thank you! I had checked and it works for some older versions.

Answer (score 3):

Please, read http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/ReadMe:

> Packages related to many database system must be linked to the exact 
>   version of the database system the user has installed, hence it does 
>   not make sense to provide binaries for packages
>       RMySQL, ROracle, ora, TSMySQL, dbConnect
>   although it is possible to install such packages from sources by
>       install.packages('packagename', type='source')
>   after reading the manual 'R Installation and Administration'.

Since RMySQL requires compilation, you need the [Windows toolset](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset).